# why elasticsearch 0.19.12 stores long as integer

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this in elasticsearch

```
.startObject("mylongfield").field("type", "long").field("store", "true").field("index", "not_analyzed").endObject()

Map<String, Object> row
row.put("mylongfield", Long.valueOf("0").longValue());
OR
row.put("mylongfield", Long.valueOf(0L).longValue());
```

when i get later the map

```
resultMap = searchHit.sourceAsMap()
resultMap.get("mylongfield") ... IT IS AN INTEGER ?!?
```

Why is ealsticsearch storing my long as integer?

Comment: There must be an error in your mapping, probably it wasn't digested by elasticsearch. Can you post your mapping and check whether you get it back from elasticsearch using the get mapping api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered similar behaviour using Elasticsearch 0.90.5 - the value of the data seems to override the mapping.

The same issue is discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elasticsearch/getsource%2420integer%2420long/elasticsearch/jxIY22TmA8U/PyqZPPyYQ0gJ). If I understand correctly, this is happening because Elasticseach uses Jackson to convert the JSON data to a Map, and this is done based on the values. I've resorted to using instanceof to determine the class of the returned Object.

Comment: and i think, that elasticsearch checks the size and stores the value in Integer if appropriate, otherwise in Long, if the value is too big for the Integer. Maybe for some performance issues

Comment: Now i think the only one solution is to check which instance of the returned object is ... and then convert